# SQL JOIN equivalent in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

these are my Models

> > User -> has many Pins
> >     Pins -> has many votes
> >     vote -> has a user_id and pin_id

How do I get all the Pins that are voted by the user in the most effective way? Basically, I want to emulate this query in Ruby.

```
SELECT * FROM PINS a JOIN VOTES b ON a.id = b.pin_id WHERE b.user_id = current_user.id
```

How can I do it?
I can use, `db.execute`, but can't I do anything without using SQL?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that a vote `belongs to` a `user`,  a `user` should have_many `votes`, and you can just get the pins via a has many through association

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :votes
   has_many voted_pins, through: :votes, source: :pin
```